# Using Kafka low-level API, should I commit the offset when finished fetching data?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

```
public void run() {
    // find the meta data about the topic and partition we are interested in
    PartitionMetadata metadata = findLeader(a_seedBrokers, a_port, a_topic, a_partition);
    if (metadata == null) {
        System.out.println("Can't find metadata for Topic and Partition. Exiting");
        return;
    }
    if (metadata.leader() == null) {
        System.out.println("Can't find Leader for Topic and Partition. Exiting");
        return;
    }
    String leadBroker = metadata.leader().host();
    String clientName = "Client_" + a_topic + "_" + a_partition;
    SimpleConsumer consumer = new SimpleConsumer(leadBroker, a_port, 100000, 64 * 1024, clientName);
    long readOffset = getLastOffset(consumer,a_topic, a_partition, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime(), clientName);
    //long readOffset = getLastOffset(consumer,a_topic, a_partition, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime(), clientName);
    int numErrors = 0;
    while (a_maxReads > 0) {
        if (consumer == null) {
            consumer = new SimpleConsumer(leadBroker, a_port, 100000, 64 * 1024, clientName);
        }
        FetchRequest req = new FetchRequestBuilder()
                .clientId(clientName)
                .addFetch(a_topic, a_partition, readOffset, 100000) // Note: this fetchSize of 100000 might need to be increased if large batches are written to Kafka
                .build();
        FetchResponse fetchResponse = consumer.fetch(req);
        if (fetchResponse.hasError()) {
            numErrors++;
            // Something went wrong!
            short code = fetchResponse.errorCode(a_topic, a_partition);
            System.out.println("Error fetching data from the Broker:" + leadBroker + " Reason: " + code);
            if (numErrors > 5) break;
            if (code == ErrorMapping.OffsetOutOfRangeCode())  {
                // We asked for an invalid offset. For simple case ask for the last element to reset
                readOffset = getLastOffset(consumer,a_topic, a_partition, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime(), clientName);
                continue;
            }
            consumer.close();
            consumer = null;
            try {
                leadBroker = findNewLeader(leadBroker, a_topic, a_partition, a_port);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            continue;
        }
        numErrors = 0;
        long numRead = 0;
        for (MessageAndOffset messageAndOffset : fetchResponse.messageSet(a_topic, a_partition)) {
            long currentOffset = messageAndOffset.offset();
            if (currentOffset < readOffset) {
                System.out.println("Found an old offset: " + currentOffset + " Expecting: " + readOffset);
                continue;
            }
            readOffset = messageAndOffset.nextOffset();
            ByteBuffer payload = messageAndOffset.message().payload();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[payload.limit()];
            payload.get(bytes);
            try {
                dataPoints.add(simpleAPIConsumer.parse(simpleAPIConsumer.deserializing(bytes)));//add data to List
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            numRead++;
            a_maxReads--;
        }
        if (numRead == 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }
    simpleAPIConsumer.dataHandle(dataPoints);//Handel Data
    if (consumer != null) consumer.close();
}
```

I found this method in Kafka source. Should I use it?

```
/**
 * Commit offsets for a topic to Zookeeper
 * @param request a [[kafka.javaapi.OffsetCommitRequest]] object.
 * @return a [[kafka.javaapi.OffsetCommitResponse]] object.
 */
 def commitOffsets(request: kafka.javaapi.OffsetCommitRequest):kafka.javaapi.OffsetCommitResponse = {
   import kafka.javaapi.Implicits._
   underlying.commitOffsets(request.underlying)
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of committing an offset after every fetch is to achieve at-least-once (see Matthias J Sax's comment below) processing.
You need to make sure that you commit offset once you processed the message (where "process" means whatever you do with a message after you pull it out from Kafka). Like you're wrapping message processing and offset commit into a transaction, where either both succeed or fail.
This way, if your client crashes you'll be able to start from the correct offset after you restart.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax could you elaborate ? https://medium.com/@jaykreps/exactly-once-support-in-apache-kafka-55e1fdd0a35f says you can get exactly-once by writing offset and derived state to DB, or storing both idempotently. So what is in the kafka commit that is lacking comparing to these 2 solutions ?

Comment: The blog say `Store the offsets in the same DB as the derived state and update both in a transaction.` -- committing offsets to Kafka is not part of any transaction using the consumer (you can make it part of a transaction using the new Kafka transactions as of v0.11 -- for this case, the producer commits offsets and thus makes them part of the transaction). -- For idempotence: if all state changes are idempotent, that committing offsets to Kafka is sufficient. Note, that you don't need to commit offset after each fetch to get this property though.

Comment: My point is, that the commit frequency has nothing to do with any processing guarantees. The answer indicates something else: namely, that "you get exactly-once if you commit after each fetch" -- not even sure, if the answer suggest to commit before or after processing the data. It's very imprecise. Also "Like you're wrapping message processing and offset commit into a transaction" is not possible with the consumer.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax why wouldn't it be possible to have a critical section in your consumer code that simply doesn't commit offset if your downstream processing fails?

Comment: You can do this, but it doesn't give you exactly-once: if you don't commit and wait for some successful downstream processing, and the processing finished successful and you then fail before committing, you would process the data again -- this is at-least-once guarantee.

Comment: I stumbled upon this after all these years. Good point. Edited the answer.